# ddplyr summarize by year, include count of year

Tags: r, plyr

This should be super simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am using the `ggplot2movies` library to get the dataframe `movies` and I am trying to summarize the data into a dataframe that is easier to graph with. In case you don't want to load the `ggplot2movies` library, a sample of the relevant data is:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   year rating
  <int>  <dbl>
1  1971    6.4
2  1939    6  
3  1941    8.2
4  1996    8.2
5  1975    3.4
6  2000    4.3
```

I have the following successful code, based on the `plyr` library:

```
years <- ddply(movies,"year",summarize,rating=mean(rating))
```

Which gives such a result, perfect for a plot or line chart:

```
> head(years)
  year   rating
1 1893 7.000000
2 1894 4.888889
3 1895 5.500000
4 1896 5.269231
5 1897 4.677778
6 1898 5.040000
```

However, I can't sort out a way to add a count column, in order to have a third variable, such as `size`, which can visualize the volume of movies produced each year on the plot chart. It should be something simple like:

```
years <- ddply(movies,"year",summarize,rating=mean(rating),count=count(years))
```

However, this gives an error:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'groups' applied to an object of class "character".

I could add a column to the original dataframe that is just a repeating value of 1, and then sum that column. But with how versatile and useful R is, I think there is some much more simple and appropriate way to do it within the ddplyr function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `n()` to give the count.

```
library(ggplot2movies)
library(dplyr)

data("movies")

movies %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(rating = mean(rating),
            years = n()) -> mvs

head(mvs, 10)
## A tibble: 10 x 3
#    year rating years
#   <int>  <dbl> <int>
# 1  1893   7        1
# 2  1894   4.89     9
# 3  1895   5.5      3
# 4  1896   5.27    13
# 5  1897   4.68     9
# 6  1898   5.04     5
# 7  1899   4.28     9
# 8  1900   4.73    16
# 9  1901   4.68    28
#10  1902   4.9      9
```

Another solution is with package `plyr`, as suggested by the OP.

```
library(plyr)

mvs2 <- ddply(movies, "year", summarize, 
              rating = mean(rating), years = length(year))
all.equal(mvs, mvs2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple! Maybe you can edit your answer to include the `plyr` answer, in case someone in the future finds this question. `years <- ddply(movies,"year",summarize,rating=mean(rating),count=n())`

Comment: `years=length(year)` worked for me too if that sounds correct

Comment: @JaredC Done, see at end.

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Thanks, I used it in the edit, following the OP's suggestion.